# Solve 4th order PDE using Finite Cosine Fourier Transform to verify solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

[Boundary Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvqpg.jpg)
[Finite Fourier Transform Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZhlo.jpg)

From the PDE shown above I am trying to solve it using the finite cosine fourier transform.

When applying the finite fourier cosine transform I get the ODE with conditions shown above
U_{tttt} + (n^4)*U = 0

however I cannot seem to find a way to solve this, then apply the reverse finite cosine fourier transform and get the solution as shown in the picture above. A method or ideas to find out would be most helpful
​

Comment: If you insert the expansion $u(x,t)=\sum U_n(t)\cos(nx)$ into the equation, you should get a different power. Also, what are the ways in which a cosine series can be zero or constant?

Comment: I don’t get how using that has anything to do with finite fourier cosine transforms though

Comment: Also Cos(n*Pi) != 0 is the boundary conditions are not satisfied with that solution

Comment: Please explain "finite" in this context. I am only aware of a discrete cosine transform DCT, and the expansion in a cosine series. Here it appears as if you started with the expansion, but computed the derivatives wrong. /// Also please use mathjax, you can use subscripts as derivation indicators also for a shorter format of the boundary conditions.

Comment: I have added the definition of the finite cosine fourier transform next to the boundary conditions

Comment: Yes, that is the formula for the Fourier series expansion and its coefficient functionals. How the factors of the reconstruction identity are distributed is a question of taste.

Comment: But I don’t get how to solve it using that method and get the solution given in the question

Comment: Essentially you get that the series is trivial, all $U_n$ zero except $U_0$, which has to be a cubic polynomial satisfying the 4 boundary conditions.

Comment: But when I solve the PDE with the method I was asked to I get the 4th order ODE with arguments n and t and I have to idea how to get the cubic polynomial solution from there